# function in peoplecode which takes in timezoneoffset of UTC and calculate timezone?

Tags: peoplesoft

I am calling a service which standardizes a given address and also gives timezone of the result in UTC offset (ex: -5:00 etc).

Is there a function in peoplecode which takes in timezoneoffset of UTC and calculate timezone ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:
[DateTimeToTimeZone](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E38689_01/pt853pbr0/eng/pt/tpcl/langref_PeopleCodeBuilt-inFunctionsandLanguageConstructs-073e6a.html#DateTimeToTimeZone-073de6)

DateTimeToTimeZone
Syntax

DateTimeToTimeZone(OldDateTime, SourceTimeZone, DestinationTimeZone)
Description

Use the DateTimeToTimeZone function to convert DateTime values from the DateTime specified by SourceTimeZone to the DateTime specified by DestinationTimeZone.

Considerations Using this Function
Typically, this function is used in PeopleCode, not for displaying time. If you take a DateTime value, convert it from base time to client time, then try to display this time, depending on the user settings, when the time is displayed the system might try to do a second conversion on an already converted DateTime. This function could be used as follows: suppose a user wanted to check to make sure a time was in a range of times on a certain day, in a certain timezone. If the times were between 12 AM and 12 PM in EST, these resolve to 9 PM and 9 AM PST, respectively. The start value is after the end value, which makes it difficult to make a comparison. This function could be used to do the conversion for the comparison, in temporary fields, and not displayed at all.

Example

The following example. TESTDTTM, is a DateTime field with a value 01/01/99 10:00:00. This example converts TESTDTTM from Pacific standard time (PST) to eastern standard time (EST).

&NEWDATETIME = DateTimeToTimeZone(TESTDTTM, "PST", "EST");
&NEWDATETIME will have the value 01/01/99 13:00:00 because EST is three hours ahead of PST on 01/01/99, so three hours are added to the DateTime value.